# Programmatically Setting Linker Flags in CMake + Xcode

Tags: xcode, cmake

I am attempting to add to the `Other Linker Flags` that are generated for the Xcode project. However, I am having a problem when it comes to escaping characters:

```
target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-some-simple-flag>
    $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-Wcomplex-flag,\$\(SRCROOT\)/SomeFile.cpp>
    $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:\$\{SOME_VARIABLE\}>
)
```

The simple flag is working, but the other two types are ending up escaped with single quotes in Xcode:

```
-some-simple-flag
'-Wcomplex-flag,/some/dir/SomeFile.cpp'
'${SOME_VARIABLE}'
```

I have also tried with specifying as strings, e.g. `"\$\{SOME_VARIABLE\}"` but this ends up as `'"${SOME_VARIABLE}"'` in Xcode, same with `"-Wcomplex-flag,$(SRCROOT)/SomeFile.cpp"` going to `"-Wcomplex-flag,/some/dir/SomeFile.cpp"`

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?